C++ concepts function template has already been defined
The following code works fine.
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct MyStruct;

template <std::floating_point FloatingPoint>
struct MyStruct<FloatingPoint> {
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << "FloatingPoint\n";
    }
};

template <std::integral Integral>
struct MyStruct<Integral> {
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Integral\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct<char>::print();
    MyStruct<float>::print();
}

Output:
Integral
FloatingPoint

However, if I try to split function declarations with definitions, compiler errors occur.
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct MyStruct;

template <std::floating_point FloatingPoint>
struct MyStruct<FloatingPoint> {
    static void print();
};

template <std::integral Integral>
struct MyStruct<Integral> {
    static void print();
};

template <std::floating_point FloatingPoint>
void MyStruct<FloatingPoint>::print()
{
    std::cout << "FloatingPoint\n";
}

template <std::integral Integral>
void MyStruct<Integral>::print()
{
    std::cout << "Integral\n";
}

int main()
{
    MyStruct<char>::print();
    MyStruct<float>::print();
}

main.cpp(24,26): error C2995: 'void MyStruct<FloatingPoint>::print(void)': function template has already been defined
main.cpp(9,17): message : see declaration of 'MyStruct<FloatingPoint>::print'
main.cpp(27,1): error C3855: 'MyStruct<FloatingPoint>': template parameter 'FloatingPoint' is incompatible with the declaration
main.cpp(32,22): error C2065: 'print': undeclared identifier

Is it possible to split the definition?
Furthermore, I would like to know if this specialization approach is fine.

I do not see any reason for the compiler to complain here. The code looks well-formed to me. Only MSVC complains about it, so I suspect it is a MSVC bug.

It seems it works fine if the structs are declared.
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct MyStruct;

template <std::floating_point FloatingPoint>
struct MyStruct<FloatingPoint>;

template <std::integral Integral>
struct MyStruct<Integral>;

template <std::floating_point FloatingPoint>
struct MyStruct<FloatingPoint> {
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << "FloatingPoint\n";
    }
};

template <std::integral Integral>
struct MyStruct<Integral> {
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Integral\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct<char>::print();
    MyStruct<float>::print();
}

Output:
Integral
FloatingPoint


"if the structs are declared" -> "if the partial specializations are forward-declared". The definitions following them are also declarations. So if this changes the compilers behavior, it is definitively something wrong with the compiler.

But wait, you didn't actually split the declaration and definition of the member functions here. So why is that relevant? The code you are showing here now also worked without the forward-declarations, no?

@user17732522 Yes, it worked without forward declarations, as I stated in the first code snippet in the question.

Then how does you answer answer the question??

@user17732522 I would like to split declarations with definitions. This is not a complete answer explaining possible MSVC bug but partially achieves what I want. I would happily accept any other answer that provides more insight.

"I would like to split declarations with definitions.": But which definitions do you want to have separate declarations for? The partial specializations themselves or the member functions of the partial specializations? These are two completely distinct problems and solving one won't help you when you need the other.

@user17732522 I agree with you. Partial specializations are meaningless when the member functions do not exist. The reason why I want to have separate declarations and definitions in the first place is because I want to improve the readability of the header file. This answer is what I used as a workaround to give at least an impression on what is going on.
